# Must I care about the padding at the end of a C++ struct? I promise I won't use it in an array

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings, clang++, memory-alignment

I have a struct, and **don't want implicit padding**.

```
#include <cstdint>
struct foo
{
  uint8_t a;
  uint32_t b;
};
static_assert(sizeof(foo) == 8, "");
```

I turn on **-Wpadded** warning.

```
> g++ test.cpp -c -Wpadded -std=c++14
test.cpp:5:12: warning: padding struct to align 'foo::b' [-Wpadded]
   uint32_t b;
            ^

> clang++ test.cpp -c -Wpadded -std=c++14
test.cpp:5:12: warning: padding struct 'foo' with 3 bytes to align 'b' [-Wpadded]
  uint32_t b;
           ^
1 warning generated.
```

That's great, and that's what I want.

I'll now switch the members around. I don't care about padding at the end to make the struct of the proper alignment. I'd rather just have the size minimised.

```
#include <cstdint>
struct foo
{
  uint32_t b;
  uint8_t a;
};
static_assert(sizeof(foo) == 5, "");

> g++ test.cpp -c -Wpadded -std=c++14
test.cpp:2:8: warning: padding struct size to alignment boundary [-Wpadded]
 struct foo
        ^
test.cpp:7:1: error: static assertion failed:
 static_assert(sizeof(foo) == 5, "");
 ^

> clang++ test.cpp -c -Wpadded -std=c++14
test.cpp:2:8: warning: padding size of 'foo' with 3 bytes to alignment boundary [-Wpadded]
struct foo
       ^
test.cpp:7:1: error: static_assert failed ""
static_assert(sizeof(foo) == 5, "");
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

That gives me a warning that I don't want.

**How can I get a warning or compile-time error if implicit padding is added, but not if padding is missing at the end to align the whole struct?** I'm not interested in using it in an array. Or is that a risky and careless thing permit? I do need instances of the struct to be aligned properly.

Is there an attribute or modifier that would achieve the same effect?

Comment: You could use `#pragma pack(1)` or whatever g++'s version of that is ... but that would also pack your first struct

Comment: What's the rationale for not wanting this padding present?

Comment: @M.M Using #pragma pack(1) equivalent gives "unaligned memory access" traps at runtime on my architecture, so that's not something I want to do. If I could work around or fix that, that would be wonderful too.

Comment: @M.M Primarily wanting to preserve/minimise the size of the structure. Preserve (where possible) for compatibility reasons.

Comment: You maybe already know this, but the ideal is to design the code so that still works the same regardless of how the struct is padded.

Comment: The layout of the struct is very important and must be prescribed; I'm willing to trade a bit of portability for that (but minimising the damage).

Comment: If you want to rearrange your members such that `sizeof(foo)==5` and there's no unaligned access, then I have to inform you that miracles don't normally occur.

Comment: You are talking about the arbitrary C++ restriction on the sizeof operator to return numeric values that are a multiple of the C++ alignof value. This dates back to the C++0x days where we had no alignof operator and the size of array memory should had been still calculatable despite. Removing this arbitrary language restriction requires utmost care due to sync with C and the risk to break compatibility of existing C++ code. https://en.cppreference.com/w/Talk:cpp/language/sizeof

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
static_assert(offsetof(foo, b) == offsetof(foo, a) + sizeof(uint8_t), "");
```

Of course you'll need to add one assert per member after the first one, or change the above to include all the fields, e.g. if `c` is the last field:

```
static_assert(offsetof(foo, c) == sizeof(uint8_t) + sizeof(uint32_t), "");
```

Now you may be wondering how to make this more automatic.  You can use Boost.Fusion if you want...here's a question I asked and answered along those lines:

[Boost Fusion: validate adapted struct member ordering at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762113/boost-fusion-validate-adapted-struct-member-ordering-at-compile-time)

You'd use the same approach: sum the size of all fields up to the last one, and check if the offset of the last field is the same.

Comment: The static_asserts for each member is not scalable if you have, say, 15 members.. :( Thanks, Boost Fusion looks heavyweight, but I'll check it out...

Comment: @JetskiS-type: Boost Fusion is heavy indeed, but you can use it in a single .cpp file which just does `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT()` and implements the checks you want.  Then the rest of your build won't depend on it.